# Proof for a prime number equation

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, prime-numbers, geometric-series

Let x and n be positive integers such that $$1 + x + x^2 + x^3 ... + x^{n-1}$$ is a prime number. Then show that n is a prime number.

So I have summed up the GP and equated it to y which is a prime number. I have no clue how I should proceed forward. Can you please help me out ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say $n=ab$ where $a,b>1$. Since $$1 + x + x^2 + x^3 ... + x^{n-1} ={x^n-1\over x-1}$$

$$={x^{ab}-1\over x-1}={(x^a-1)((x^a)^{b-1}+...(x^a)^2+x^a+1)\over x-1}$$

$$ = \underbrace{(x^{a-1}+...+x^2+x+1)}_{>1}\cdot \underbrace{((x^a)^{b-1}+...(x^a)^2+x^a+1)}_{>1}$$

a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your method. Thats a very interesting way to look at it. I would've never been able to fathom such fancy manipulations to prove this.

Comment: It is just a matter of experience...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show that if $n$ is not a prime, the expression can be factored. For instance, for $n=4$, we have
$$
1+x+x^2+x^3=(1+x^2)(1+x)
$$
(It may be easier to show that $x^n-1$ can be factored *differently* than $(x-1)(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1})$)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I understood that factorization would play a role, I did not know I should prove it for a general n.